# socket.io only works locally with nginx

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io

(PHP runs with nginx, and I use socket.io from NODEJS)
If I try my website locally (using 2 web diffenrets web browzers), everything works.
But If I host my website (hosted in my house), I still can access to it with an other computer, but the functions of my app.js are not executed...

Here is my last error.log from nginx :

```
2016/05/03 14:11:00 [error] 25016#25016: *108 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Only variables should be passed by reference in /var/www/html/outer_treatment/game/add_message_discussion.php on line 55" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.1.16, server: default, request: "POST /outer_treatment/game/add_message_discussion.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.1.13", referrer: "http://192.168.1.13/game.php"
```

in my page where the NodeJS functions are handled: (located in : /view/game/index.php)

```
# into the <head>
<script src="/NODEJS/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
# into the <body>
var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:3000');
```

And my nodeJs file app.js : (located in : /NODEJS/app.js)

```
var app = require('express')(),
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
fs = require('fs');
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket)
{

// here my functions

});

server.listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
```

Here is my default file of Nginx (located in : /etc/nginx/sites-available)

```
# the IP(s) on which node server is running.
upstream app_default {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {
# Default listen lines :
#listen 80 default_server;
#listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

# NODE JS listen
#listen 0.0.0.0:80;
listen 80;

#root /usr/share/nginx/html;
root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

#server_name localhost;
server_name default;

location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules;

    #NODEJS configuration :
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # the websockets :
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ \.css {
    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
}

location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
}

location ~ \.png$ {
    try_files $uri $uri /$1;
}
}
```

Thanks you, I hope my problem is enough accurate

Comment: Do you have anything in your browser Console view ? Are you sure that from the other computer, the Node.js app is called (adding logging on the Node.js app should help) ? What exactly works from the other computer and what does not ?

Comment: there is no any particular alert in the console view...
from the other computer, what works is what doesn't work with NODEJS, the nodeJS functions linked with game.php dont work

Comment: if I write a message from the app.js it works but if I use socket.io it doesnt work... its weird

Comment: You declare a pool of upstream servers named `app_default` that you does not use anywhere else. Does the `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;` line should be `proxy_pass http://app_default;`? Also, be sure tu use Nginx > 1.3

Comment: I ve changed this line, but the problem still occurs

Comment: is it normal that in the browzer console view of the client, it reads that it connects to 127.0.0.1:3000 with socket.io, but it should be instead the web IP of the server no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved my problem, in the index.php file I ve modified

```
var socket = io.connect('127.0.0.1:3000');
```

by

```
var socket = io.connect('http://'+window.location.host+':3000');
```

everything works now ! :)

Comment: Great ! That explains why from distant computer it wouldn't work. (;